# Is there a way to avoid code duplication in multiple similar functions?

Tags: c, embedded, code-duplication

I am writing a family of functions which are to be embedded in a small micro-controller operating at very near real time, so every clock cycle counts.  The functions are almost identical.

The only way that I can see to do this without duplicating vast chunks of code is to use the really ugly and frowned upon method of declaring the code in an include file which is then intentionally included multiple times.

The following works to demonstrate the concept:

```
// func.inc

// The absence of an include guard is intentional, as each time this file gets included
// the output will be different

void FUNC(int x)
{
    /* SNIP - lots and lots of code that is duplicated between 
       variant A and B (and more) of the function
    for ( ... 4096 ) 
    {
        for( lots more nested loops)
        {
    */
    // IMPORTANT - I do not want to call functions here as it is
    // in a tight loop withconsecutive memory accesses of 
    // different sizes of strided sparse arrays
#ifdef A
    printf("A %d\n", x);
#endif
#ifdef B
    printf("B %d\n", x);
#endif
    /*
        }
    }
    */
```

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>

#define FUNC func_A  
#define A
#include "func.inc"
#undef A
#undef FUNC

#define FUNC func_B  
#define B
#include "func.inc"
#undef B
#undef FUNC

#define FUNC func_AB  
#define A
#define B
#include "func.inc"

int main()
{
    func_A(10);
    func_B(20);
    func_AB(30);

    printf("Done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that whilst this works, it looks hideous, and might be very confusing to someone else trying to understand it.  Using a pointer to a function is too inefficient to be a viable option in this case.

Is there a solution that anyone can suggest without simply duplicating several slightly different versions of the same function?

Comment: You can use `static inline` for the rest of the stuff.

Comment: Are you using a compiler that lacks an optimizer? The optimizer will inline functions and fold constant expressions for you when it generates code. You should not need to jump through all of these hoops. At a *minimum*, start with the code that is readable and make sense, then check to see what the compiler outputs with maximum optimizations. Only go back and start fiddling with it if the compiler *isn't* generating what you think it should.

Comment: You should `#undef FUNC` so you don't get warnings about non-benign redefinition. This was edited in, which seems like an odd way to get the point across, but still.

Comment: @birdwes The file endings (by which GCC determines the languages by default) of your file is `.c`. You should not just switch between C and C++. The languages have different rules. In C++ you would maybe use function templates, but in any case you would rely on the compiler's inlining decisions for the most part anyway, which is why you should explain what is wrong with a function call.

Comment: @birdwes, can you please clarify whether you want C code or C++ code? They are not the same language, and you need to tag the question accordingly.

Comment: @S.S.Anne If you need a concrete example it might be a bit long to read, and probably of no relevance to most readers.  It's the innermost loops of a Q15 fixed point integer calculation of FFT Hilbert Transform for a software defined radio, to run on an ESP32 MCU. Think of "A" in the example as being the "Real / I" ,"B" as being the "Imaginary / Q", complex numbers.  I need an "I", a "Q", and "IQ" variants  I've benchmarked it with three individual functions and I get a 10% performance speedup, so the normal arguments about not over-optimizing code do not apply here. It really counts. Thanks

Comment: @CodyGray , the real code is wrapped in an extern "C" at the moment, so I could eject into C++ if I get a better benchmark?  The only reason it is in straight C is to avoid any unanticipated constructions from the C++ compiler, and perhaps later portability on other chips.  I write the code in MSVC for first time testing and then port it down to my target chip, so C is the baseline.

Comment: That makes very little sense. C++ is an actual *language*; it isn't a set of vendor-specific extensions to the C language, so there are no "portability" concerns or "unanticipated constructions" that you are going to experience. (There *are* implicit calls to constructors in C++, but you know they're happening, because you wrote the constructor!) Often, you can get *better* code from a C++ compiler than a C compiler because you can take advantage of features like template metaprogramming and other no-cost abstractions in your code that a modern optimizer can completely elide.

Comment: Aside from that, it's your decision which language you want to use, but for the purposes of a Stack Overflow question, you do need to pick one. If you want to start by asking about C, you can do that, and then follow up with a second question about C++ if you aren't satisfied with the C answers. But as someone who writes signal-processing code for embedded systems as their day job, I really don't think your "C-first" approach makes any sense and seems to come from some fundamental misunderstandings, or at least failure to appreciate the current state of technology.

Comment: @CodyGray , It's a HAM radio project in investigating the absolute lowest cost device that a home constructor could reproduce.  I don't want to get into FPGA style solutions that cost lots of money and time to learn the toolchain.  I'm normally here only in a professional basis, but this time it's just a hobby question.  Whatever the final purpose, it's still one that perplexes many writers about C/C++ style for #includes .

Comment: @birdwes If you can use C++, search up `std::complex`. It will simplify your task greatly.

Comment: @S.S.Anne the ROM in the MCU is too small to take std:: .  I will add a code snippet tomorrow.  It's past 3:30am here.

void FFT_TransformRadix2(PFFT_CTX pfft_ctx, PFFT_COMPLEX_32 dst, PFFT_COMPLEX_32 src);

Comment: You should post a more representative code example since your assertions about performance requirements, function pointers and "tight loops" etc. are not exemplified here.  You'll get the best solution if you present more realistic code.

Comment: You are using printf but can't afford a few extra function calls because of function call overhead? That's utter nonsense, printf is most likely 99% of the bottleneck in this code. Also when talking performance here, it makes a _huge_ difference if this is a high end part with data cache & flash wait states, or a low end part like a 8 bitter.

Comment: @S.S.Anne , without posting reams of code, lets just say that the real code is extremely similar to something similar to lines 288 to 376, which I wrote back in 2013: [https://sourceforge.net/p/fftforarmv6/code/ci/master/tree/fft.cpp](https://sourceforge.net/p/fftforarmv6/code/ci/master/tree/fft.cpp) .  That piece of code was based on chapter 6 of the following: [https://www.renesas.com/us/en/doc/DocumentServer/024/U17285EE2V0AN00.pdf](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/doc/DocumentServer/024/U17285EE2V0AN00.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

It's not really clear what's pseudo code and real code here, but overall you should not use `#define` + `#undef` + `#include` for the purpose of different code generation. (You *could* do it with "X macros" though as a last resort. Not an ideal solution but better than this.)

The solution to " IMPORTANT - I do not want to call functions here" is to call functions.

Function inlining has been a thing for some 30 years and 20 years ago C got explicit language support for it. And nowadays compilers are much better than programmers to determine what to inline. I'll make an example with explicit `inline` just to demonstrate that calling functions does *not* affect performance, if done correctly.

With traditional C, you would do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void SNIP (void)
{
  puts(__func__);
}

static inline void A_stuff (int val)
{
  printf("%s %d\n", __func__, val);
}

static inline void B_stuff (int val)
{
  printf("%s %d\n", __func__, val);
}

typedef enum { A=1, B=2 } AB_t;

void func(AB_t ab, int val)
{
  SNIP();

  if(ab & A)
    A_stuff(val);
  if(ab & B)
    B_stuff(val);
}

int main()
{
  func(A, 10);
  func(B, 20);
  func(A|B, 30);

  printf("Done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

That's the sane solution. The only functions that are actually called in the generated machine code are `func` and the printing functions.

Alternatively, you could have done code generation with "X macros" too - these exist solely for the purpose of avoiding code repetition, at the expense of readability. Wouldn't really recommend it here, but I'll include an example for completeness:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FUNC_LIST \
  X(A,  10)       \
  X(B,  20)       \
  X(AB, 30)       \


static inline void SNIP (void)
{
  puts(__func__);
}

static inline void A_stuff (int val)
{
  printf("%s %d\n", __func__, val);
}

static inline void B_stuff (int val)
{
  printf("%s %d\n", __func__, val);
}

static inline void AB_stuff (int val)
{
  A_stuff(val);
  B_stuff(val);
}

#define X(opt, val) void func_##opt (int x) { SNIP(); opt##_stuff(x); }
  FUNC_LIST
#undef X


int main()
{
  #define X(opt, val) func_##opt(val),
    FUNC_LIST
  #undef X

  printf("Done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This is quite unreadable just like the original code, except "X macros" are something of a de facto standard for icky macro tricks to avoid code repetition.

This creates multiple functions just like a C++ template, so it isn't ideal for that reason as well.

Comment: this adds the overhead of the "if" statement.  Conditional branch statements take clock cycles.  When it's in the middle of tight nested loops, they add up.

Comment: @birdwes It's not in the middle, it's just before it. And it's just one statement... couple of CPU cycles - it doesn't lead to cache misses, it doesn't affect branch prediction, it's not even worth mentioning. I work with hard real-time systems every day, and things are rarely ever as critical as people make them out to be. Most of the time it's just someone getting the bad idea that some code has to be optimized to oblivion, before it is even benchmarked. If this code actually had hard real-time constraints, there would be timers, timeouts, interrupts etc.

Comment: Also, replacing this if statement with a function pointer look-up table is trivial, but then you _would_ get function call overhead instead. Bad optimization on a low end MCU, good optimization on a high end MCU.

Comment: @birdwes Bottom line here is: you can't optimize for "as fast as possible on a generic computer" without any real-time spec even mentioned. You must optimize for a very specific system, and you must have a specification over how long a routine is allowed to take - if it is even critical in the first place. Everything else is so-called "pre-mature optimization" and this example does smell of that quite a lot.

Comment: @birdwes [Why Premature Optimization is the Root of All Evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

Comment: @S.S.Anne I am familiar with that link.  I totally agree in principle.  This is not premature though... it's the final stage before it gets blown into the flash ROM.

Comment: @birdwes Then write idiomatic code (the first solution) and if it's too slow then improve it.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit:** The question was originally tagged with C++, hence the answer.

---

Make a template!

```
// func.hpp

#ifndef FUNCITON_HPP
#define FUNCITON_HPP

enum Specifier : int {
        A = 1 << 0,
        B = 1 << 1,
};


#include <cstdio>

template <auto sp>
void foo(int x)
{
        /* SNIP - lots and lots of code that is duplicated between
           variant A and B (and more) of the function
        for ( ... 4096 )
        {
            for( lots more nested loops)
            {
        */
        // IMPORTANT - I do not want to call functions here as it is
        // in a tight loop withconsecutive memory accesses of
        // different sizes of strided sparse arrays
        if constexpr (static_cast<bool>(sp & Specifier::A)) {
                std::printf("A %d\n", x);
        }
        if constexpr (static_cast<bool>(sp & Specifier::B)) {
                std::printf("B %d\n", x);
        }
}

#endif //!FUNCITON_HPP
```

Then

```
// func.cpp
#include "func.hpp"

auto constexpr func_a = foo<Specifier::A>; // Could also use a #define 
auto constexpr func_b = foo<Specifier::B>;
auto constexpr func_ab = foo<Specifier::A | Specifier::B>;


int main()
{
        func_a(1);
        func_b(1);
        func_ab(1);
}
```

Comment: `const` rvalue references are pointless. You can use `const` lvalue references, which make more sense. `if constexpr` is a relatively new feature. Usually embedded systems don't have support for features from newer standards.

Comment: I spent time on this answer and removing the "C++" tag invalidates my answer, which is frowned up on.

Comment: The question was always about C, from revision 1. The title explicitly said it needed to be done in C. The C++ tag was erroneous, and has since been removed so it doesn't lead others astray as it apparently did you. If the compiler that came with your embedded system isn't standards-compliant or doesn't support the features you want, consider swapping it out for a modern version of GCC or Clang. The Gnu and LLVM code generators will emit machine code suitable for just about any microarchitecture used today, including those found in embedded systems. Their optimizers are great, too.

Comment: What is the purpose of the explicit `static_cast<bool>`? That conversion should be implicit, shouldn't it?

Comment: @walnut Visual Studio was complaining about implicit narrowing cast, so I added the explicit cast.

Comment: ok, so Clang gives an error, MSVC a warning and GCC nothing. GCC doesn't even give a diagnostic with `-pedantic-errors`. Seems that GCC is actually the wrong one here. Narrowing conversions are not allowed, although I think that is a weird decision by the standard for conversion to `bool`.

Comment: @walnut it seems to me that conversion to `bool` is not a narrowing conversion; the definition of "narrowing conversion" doesn't include any cases of `bool` (it talks about integer types, but `bool` is not an integer type in C++). The case "converted constant expression" is specified to allow "integral conversions, but not narrowing conversions", and "integral conversions" does include conversion to bool.  Also, the `static_assert` has the same condition as `if constexpr`, so if this were disallowed then `static_assert(3, "x")` would be an error ...

Comment: @M.M The standard considers `bool` to be an *integer type*, see [basic.fundamental/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#basic.fundamental-7). And from a quick look it seems to me that that `static_assert` should indeed not compile. [dcl.dcl/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#6) together with [expr.const/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#4.7) and [dcl.init.list/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#7). Both Clang and GCC agree that `bool x{2};` is narrowing: https://godbolt.org/z/J8GoP7

Comment: @M.M The second sentence in the clause says: "*A synonym for integral type is integer type.*"

Comment: @walnut OK, I agree with you now. So the compilers are all bugged w.r.t. the `static_assert` then.

Comment: @M.M Yes seems so, but I think this rule is unintuitive given that implicit conversion in contexts requiring a `bool` is used so often and idiomatic in C++.

Comment: @walnut Yeah. Disallowing `template<int N> void f() { if constexpr(N)` seems silly on the face of it

Comment: Using auto is plain dangerous in general, but particularly so in embedded systems. You realize that you create 3 function pointers in RAM, that only get initialized during `.data` initialization? There is absolutely no reason why these shouldn't be stored in flash. Furthermore, the templates might prevent source code repetition, but you allocate 3 different functions so this will take lots of code space.

Comment: @Ludin the alternative in the question also creates 3 different functions that take identical storage. If you have a better solution than `auto const& func_a = ...`, please do share. Maybe `#define func_a ...`? I did mention that in the answer, but I didn't want to use a macro.

Comment: @Ayxan Just what I noticed: Your function references have external linkage. Remove the `&`s, then the `const` function pointers have internal linkage and don't need to be emitted. Make it `constexpr` instead of `const` to be extra sure.

Comment: @walnut thank you for the feedback. I did apply your suggestions. Could you explain why the reference makes it external but removing `&` makes it internal?

Comment: @Ayxan `const` global variables (generally) have internal linkage (in C++, but not C). Other global variables (generally) have external linkage. `const auto&` is not itself top-level `const`-qualified (references cannot be `const`-qualified), so it has external linkage.